# Is there a connection between uncountable sets and exponential growth?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $S_n$ be the collection of all binary strings of length $n$.  It seems that as $n$ goes to infinity, $S_n$ becomes the set of all infinite binary strings.  Each time we increment $n$, the size of $S_n$ doubles, so $|S_n|$ is undergoing "exponential growth" with respect to $n$.

Similarly, let $C_0$ be the set $\{0, 1\}$, let $C_1$ be the set $\{0, \frac{1}{3}, \frac{2}{3}, 1\}$, let $C_3$ be the set $\{0, \frac{1}{9}, \frac{2}{9}, \frac{1}{3}, \frac{2}{3}, \frac{7}{9}, \frac{8}{9}, 1\}$, and so on.  It seems that as $n$ goes to infinity, $C_n$ becomes the Cantor set.  Again, each time we increment $n$, the size of $C_n$ doubles, so $|C_n|$ is undergoing "exponential growth" with respect to $n$.

In both of these cases, the "limiting result" of "exponential growth" is an uncountable set.

In contrast, let $K_n$ be the set of $k$-tuples of $\{1, 2, ..., n\}$.  The size of $K_n$ only undergoes "polynomial growth", and in this case, the "limiting result" (set of all $k$-tuples of positive integers) is a countable set.

> Is there a connection between uncountable sets and exponential growth?

In particular, I'm wondering if there any interesting results that generalize or extend the observations I made above.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your idea. What do you mean by sequence of sets to "become" something in the limit? Do you have some precise definition in mind? One possibility is the union of the family, but in that case your observations are not really correct - $S_n$ does not become a set of all infinite binary strings, as no infinite string is contained in the union of $S_n$. Union of sets $C_n$ defined as in the question is countable, as countable union of finite sets, hence it cannot be Cantor's set.

Answer (score 4):

You are mistaken in your first assessment. The limit case is countable.

The limit case of $S_n$ is not $2^\omega$, the set of infinite binary strings, but rather $2^{<\omega}$, the set of finite strings of arbitrary length. Similarly, $C_n$'s don't limit as the Cantor set, but rather as the set of endpoints of removed intervals, which is just a countable set.

The issue here is the same in all cases, $$\sup n^k\neq n^{\sup k}.$$

Comment: Interesting... a few clarifications: (1) how did you formalize the notion of a "limit" here, (2) is there a concrete example of an element that's in the Cantor set but not in $C_n$ for any $n$, and (3) can you please give some more context for the last expression?

Comment: (1) The limit of an increasing sequence of sets is its union; (2) $\frac14$; (3) cardinal arithmetic is often discontinuous at limits (with respect to the order topology on the cardinals).

Comment: Thanks.  Should I close this question?  (It doesn't really make sense anymore)

Comment: I don't know, it's up to you. It's a sensible question if you're unfamiliar with the clarifications, I suppose. I agree that once you are familiar with them it makes less sense than before.

Answer (score -2):

Here is an example of a connection between uncountable sets and exponential growth. Consider a binary tree of infinite depth.  Each path down the tree codes a binary string of infinite length, and all possible binary strings of infinite length are accounted for by the paths in the tree.  The Cantor Diagonal Argument shows that the set of all possible paths cannot be put into a 1-to-1 correspondence with the Natural Numbers, in other words not countable.  The branch/node count grows exponentially as one moves down the tree (it doubles at each subsequent level of the tree.)